# How to pop multiple fragment as soon as a popup is dismissed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I am stuck in a situation where I am using a fragments in the below way:

Activity -> fragment A -> fragment B -> fragment C -> Dialog Fragment

I need to go to fragment A, as soon as user clicks on a button in DialogFragment and dismisses it. All these fragment are done using .add method.

I am expecting a very optimized and simple logic, which Android gives by default rather than a customized complex one.

Comment: did you tried below code?
buttonInDialogFragment.setOnClickListener {
    
    dismiss() // dismiss the dialog

    // Pop back stack until FragmentA
    parentFragmentManager.popBackStack("FragmentATag", 0)
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use navigation graph to easily navigate between fragments. But it seems that you are a beginner. Hence you can do it as follows :

Use the following code in the onClick of the dialog you are using

```
  val count = parentFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount
        for (i in 1..count){
            if (count>1){
                parentFragmentManager.popBackStack()
            }
        }
```

Note the code is in Kotlin. Do let me know if you want it in java.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help, I came across such a solution too, can you please let me know, which one is better solution

Just before dismissing the dialogFragment, I invoked a interface which I have implemented in the parent activity. In the activity I popped the backstack till fragment B(inclusive)

```
override fun onPopupClose() {
    supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(LoginFragment.TAG,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
}
```